# Installing .apks using adb shell

Tags: android, adb

How do i install an .apks file using the adb shell?
I tried using `pm install /sdcard/TestApp.apks` but it threw an error. I've even tried googling the question but found nothing.

Comment: What is the error you got?

Comment: `apks` file format is not an official file format by Google. If you want to install it via adb you have to manually unzip and then install the contained APK files as one app. I don't know excactly how to do so using pm (comments of [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/210676/2241) my be helpful). On PC side you could use the command `adb install-multiple`.

Answer (score 0):

An `.apks` file is not an Android construct. Hence, the Android OS does not know about it, including commands like `pm`. You will need to [use `bundletool`](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/bundletool).

Comment: Are you sure the APKs file format is related to Google or PlayStore? The APKs variant I know (there may be multiple file formats with that extension) is a ZIP based third party file format developed by Android users and developers bundling multiple APK files. Google Play Store also uses multiple APK files but never bundled into an `.apks` ZIP archive.

Comment: @Robert: "Google Play Store also uses multiple APK files but never bundled into an .apks ZIP archive" -- the only place I have ever heard of it is with respect to `bundletool`, which itself is tied to Google Play. It definitely is not an Android OS thing. I have updated the answer to eliminate the Google Play reference, though.